# Subclassing file by subclassing `io.TextIOWrapper` — but what signature does its constructor have?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, subclassing

I'm trying to subclass `io.TextIOWrapper` following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23796737/974555), although my aims are different.  Starting off with this (NB: [motivation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4169762/974555)):

```
class MyTextIOFile(io.TextIOWrapper):
    def read(self, *args):
        cont = super().read(*args)
        return cont.replace("\x00", "")
```

I'm trying to open a file using my constructor using

```
In [81]: f = MyTextIOFile("file.csv")
```

but this gives:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-343e18b2e32f> in <module>()
----> 1 f = MyTextIOFile("file.csv")

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readable'
```

And indeed, it appears `io.TextIOWrapper`s constructor expects to be passed a file object.  Through trial and error, I discovered this file object needs to be opened in **binary** mode.  But I can't find documentation anywhere, and I don't feel like building on top of undocumented behaviour (indeed, one attempt to go ahead with it already lead me to problems when trying to pass my object to `csv.reader`).  What is the correct and supported way to subclass a file object in Python 3?

I'm using Python 3.5.0.

Comment: Consider using composition instead; have your class use `open` to open the file and save a reference to the object returned instead.

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure exactly what you mean — do you mean not inheriting from the `io.IOBase` family?  Ultimately I want to pass this to `csv.csvreader` and therefore my aim is to read the file stripped of all NULs (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4169762/974555)).

Comment: Right; `csv.csvreader` doesn't care what type it receives, as long as it implements the iterator protocol (i.e., has a `next` method that can be called to get the next row).

Comment: @chepner Thank you for teaching me the term composition, it is new for me and could be considered, although I don't know how many methods I'd need to implement to make it work with `csv.reader`.

Comment: Just `next`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-contents): "csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string each time its next() method is called"

Comment: @chepner Thanks for pointing that out.  For my specific purpose here composition may then be considerably easier.  Still curious to see the answer to the inheritance-approach question, though.

Answer (score 2):

I think the documentation you are looking for is

```
class io.TextIOWrapper(buffer, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, line_buffering=False)
    A buffered text stream over a BufferedIOBase binary stream. [...]
```

The first argument is a binary stream, which implies something opened in binary mode by `open`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as "fixing" your csv file, you could also use a generator:

```
# untested
def FixCsv(csv_file, *args, **kwds):
    "assumes text-mode file; removes NUL-bytes"
    if isinstance(csv_file, str):
        file_obj = open(csv_file, *args, **kwds)
    else:
        file_obj = csv_file
    for line in file_obj:
        yield line.replace('\x00','')
    file_obj.close()
```

But your problem is probably caused by a utf-16 encoded file.

Comment: It's not utf-16 encoded.  I don't know the encoding.  It's a CSV generated by Surveymonkey.  But that's a different question (I realise my question is somewhat of an XY problem).